Is Autodesk.forge C# Nuget deprecated
We have been using the Autodesk.forge C# Nuget for a backend app accessing APS services (Model Derivative) for a few months now.
I just figured that the Autodesk.forge package is now archived, and a new set of C# Nugets have been released on https://www.nuget.org/profiles/AutodeskPlatformServices.SDK.
My question is how pressing is it for us to switch from former Autodesk.forge to new AutodeskPlatformServices.SDK? Should we expect discontinued services or regression if we keep using Autodesk.forge?
Thanks.
No problem yet.
Just figured out that Autodesk.forge has been archived a few months ago.

Yes, this Nuget is now deprecated and no longer will receive any updates, the last version is 1.9.9. We are not planning to turn it off unless we give developers using it the necessary time to migrate to the new official SDK which you listed above. For now is not urgent to migrate, we will be releasing a migration guide this quarter in order to go through that process. Be alert of our newsletter and blog.
